# Weird regex behavior in bash if condition

Tags: regex, bash

I have written a small script that loops through directories (starting from a given argument directory) and prompts directories that have an `xml` file inside. Here is my code :

```
#! /bin/bash

process()
{
    LIST_ENTRIES=$(find $1 -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1)

    regex="\.xml"
    if [[ $LIST_ENTRIES =~ $regex ]]; then
        echo "$1"
    fi  

    # Process found entries
    while read -r line
    do
        if [[ -d $line ]]; then
            process $line
        fi  
    done <<< "$LIST_ENTRIES"
}

process $1
```

This code works fine. However, if I change the regex to `\.xml$` to indicate that it should match at the end of the line, the result is different, and I do not get all the right directories.

Is there something wrong with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `LIST_ENTRIES` may not have `.xml` as the last entry.

To validate, try `echo $LIST_ENTRIES`.

To overcome this, use `for` around your `if`:

```
process()
{
    LIST_ENTRIES=$(find $1 -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1)

    regex="\.xml$"

    for each in $LIST_ENTRIES; do
      if [[ $each =~ $regex ]]; then
          echo "$1"
      fi
    done

    # Process found entries
    while read -r line
    do
        if [[ -d $line ]]; then
            process $line
        fi  
    done <<< "$LIST_ENTRIES"
}

process $1
```

Comment: Oh ! You made me aware of a huge mistake ! Of course, `$LIST_ENTRIES` is a bunch of lines (separated by `\n`), and looking for `xml` match at the end will never work if some intermediate lines do contain `xml`. I can consider your suggestion as a solution for my post. Thank you :)